# Grant Linux user access to a folder and execution rights to its content

Tags: linux, bash

How to grant a Linux user access to a folder and execution rights to everything inside it?

I've got a script I need to run on a remote machine via SSH but I want to limit the rights to a specific user.

Granting the user root access is not an option, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use chown to give ownership to the directory
 `chown -r username /path/to/folder`

You may need root to do this.

You can also set permissions - `chmod 755` would give the owner full permissions and read/write permissions for everyone else. You can adjust this to taste